# Hibernate EntityManager - Closed Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I'm using EntityManagers to perform operations on the DB. However, and this happens like 20% of the time, the connection obtained by the EntityManager is closed and I can't perform any action. The EntityManager is open since i do check for that, but the connection is closed.

The code is as such:

I have a Session bean:

```
@Stateless(name = "TestDAO", mappedName = "TestDAO")
@Remote
public class TestDAOBean
  implements TestDAO
{
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="support")
  private EntityManager em;

  public TestDAOBean()
  {
  }

  public void persistObj(MyObj obj)
  {
    try
    {
      Query query = em.createNamedQuery("MyNamedQuery");
      query.setParameter("Name", "Param");
      query.setParameter("Value", "bla bla");
      query.executeUpdate();

      em.persist(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Sometimes, the NamedQuery above fails due to a "Connection Closed" error. I'm under the impression that the EJB container deals with closing the EM if it's injected and i dont need to worry about that. So i don't understand why the connection is sometimes being closed...

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes being closed"?

Comment: I mean that in most cases the above code executes successfully with no problems at all. However, 20% of the time, I get this error: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection when trying to execute the NamedQuery above. It might be a connection pool management issue but i can't put my finger on it...

Comment: But in the code above you didn't use a connection.

Comment: It's a stateless bean and is executed inside an application server. This application server is managing the connection to the database and should have an open connection to execute the function inside a transaction. It's automatic. Maybe it's a problem of configuration of the connection pool?

Comment: @eternay That's what I'm thinking too...Im working on the App Server to see if something is off but just wanted to rule out the possibility of a glitch in the code...

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code. I suppose that TestDAO is your remote business interface and that it declares at least the `persistObject(MyObj)` method. It should work.